# Apply regex pattern in jolt specification to find attribute is alphanumeric or number

Tags: json, jolt

I have a scenario where I want to populate attribute based on data value.

Input :

```
{
   "PersonName":{
      "FirstName":"03-03-1984",
      "ID":"123567",
      "Name":[
         "Betty Lou",
         "Tre Chernockxdev"
      ],
      "LastName":"Tre Chernockxdev"
   }
}
```

Output:

```
{
   "Birth":{
      "YearOfBirth":"1984"
   },
   "Employee":{
      "LastName":"Tre Chernockxdev"
   },
   "Element":{
      "Category":"Fixed"
   }
}
```

So, based on `ID` value I want to populate `Gender` attribute. If `ID` is number then populate `Category` with `Fixed` or if `ID` is alphanumeric then populate category with `Floating` value.

Jolt Spec:

```
[
   {
      "operation":"shift",
      "spec":{
         "PersonName":{
            "FirstName":{
               "*-*-*":{
                  "$(0,3)":"Birth.YearOfBirth"
               }
            },
            "LastName":"Employee.LastName",
            "ID":"Fixed|Floating"
         }
      }
   }
]
```

I also checked [jolt string function](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt/blob/master/jolt-core/src/main/java/com/bazaarvoice/jolt/modifier/function/Strings.java) but could not find a function which can be used to check the data category. Is their way where I can find whether `ID` value contains `number` or `alphanumeric`? Or can I apply the `regex pattern` to check whether data contains a `number` or `alphanumeric` value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to achieve something like [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) which is hard to get but possible:

```
[
   {
      "operation":"shift",
      "spec":{
         "PersonName":{
            "*":"&"
         }
      }
   },
   {
      "operation":"modify-overwrite-beta",
      "spec":{
         "ID":[
            "=toInteger",
            "Floating"
         ]
      }
   },
   {
      "operation":"shift",
      "spec":{
         "ID":{
            "@":"ID",
            "Floating":null,
            "*":{
               "#Fixed":"ID"
            }
         },
         "*":"&"
      }
   },
   {
      "operation":"modify-overwrite-beta",
      "spec":{
         "ID":"=lastElement(@(1,ID))"
      }
   },
   {
      "operation":"shift",
      "spec":{
         "FirstName":{
            "*-*-*":{
               "$(0,3)":"Birth.YearOfBirth"
            }
         },
         "LastName":"Employee.LastName",
         "ID":"Element.Category"
      }
   }
]
```

See also:

- [Jolt Object functions](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt/blob/master/jolt-core/src/main/java/com/bazaarvoice/jolt/modifier/function/Objects.java)